# How to change a value while dropping?

Tags: rust

I’m currently trying to understand how `drop` works. The following code crashes and I don’t understand why. From my understanding, the usage of `std::ptr::write` should prevent the destructor (edit: of the original value, here: Rc) from running (in this case nothing bad should happen beside the memory leak). But it doesn’t seem to do that as ([playpen](http://is.gd/Kotpki), compile with -O0)

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::mem;
use std::ptr;

enum Foo {
    Bar(Rc<usize>),
    Baz
}
use Foo::*;

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        match *self {
            Bar(_) => {
                unsafe { ptr::write(self, Foo::Baz) }
                //unsafe { mem::forget(mem::replace(self, Foo::Baz)) }
            }
            Baz => ()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _ = Foo::Bar(Rc::new(23));
}
```

gives an overflow error:

```
thread '<main>' panicked at 'arithmetic operation overflowed', /Users/rustbuild/src/rust-buildbot/slave/nightly-dist-rustc-mac/build/src/liballoc/rc.rs:755
```

The other variant quits with an illegal instruction. Why does that happen? How can I replace self with a value that will be properly dropped?

Comment: For my own curiosity — *why* are you trying to do this? It seems a very odd thing to do.

Comment: I’m trying to realize some small vector optimization (`enum SmallVec<T> { Small(u8, [T; SIZE]), Big(Vec<T>) }`). It appears to me, that the only way to safely drop `Small` is to manually drop the occupied entries and then replace it with the `Big` variant in order to be able to forget it.

Comment: Is it the case that your `Small` array doesn't always have `SIZE` entries in it? I'm assuming that's what the `u8` is.

Comment: Exactly. And in case it grows beyond `SIZE` the values are moved into the `Big` variant. I’m doing the same almost the same there (`ptr::read` and `ptr::write`) as in drop and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I'm not sure yet how to accomplish your goal, but</s> I can show that

> From my understanding, the usage of `std::ptr::write` should prevent the destructor from running

isn't true:

```
use std::mem;
use std::ptr;

struct Noisy;
impl Drop for Noisy {
    fn drop(&mut self) { println!("Dropping!") }
}

enum Foo {
    Bar(Noisy),
    Baz
}
use Foo::*;

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("1");

        match self {
            &mut Bar(_) => {
                println!("2");
                unsafe { ptr::write(self, Foo::Baz) }
                println!("3");
            }
            &mut Baz => {
                println!("4");
            }
        }

        println!("5");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _ = Foo::Bar(Noisy);
}
```

This prints:

```
1
2
3
5
Dropping!
```

Indicating that the destructor for `Foo::Bar` is still being run, including the destructor of `Noisy`.

A potential solution is to use [`Option::take`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take):

```
use std::mem;

struct Noisy;
impl Drop for Noisy {
    fn drop(&mut self) { println!("Dropping!") }
}

enum Foo {
    Bar(Option<Noisy>),
    Baz
}

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        match *self {
            Foo::Bar(ref mut x) => {
                unsafe { mem::forget(x.take()) }
            }
            Foo::Baz => {}
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _ = Foo::Bar(Some(Noisy));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear and refined my post. My understanding is, that `ptr::write` does simply copy `src` to `dest` without previously calling the destructor in `dst`.

Comment: @Ferio right - but this example shows that the destructor for `Noisy` **is still called**, even though you've replaced `self` with something that doesn't contain a `Noisy`. I'm guessing that the specific destructor is decided *before* the method runs, so you can't modify the variant during `Drop`, as you'd like.

Comment: Indeed, I didn’t get your example correctly on the first glance.

Comment: @Ferio that would explain your original error message - the destructor for `Rc` is still being run, but on a chunk of data that doesn't correspond to an `Rc`! It's actually *lucky* that you got a nice error message like overflow, as opposed to silent memory corruption.

Comment: Yes, and by using safe code only (`let _ = mem::replace(self, Foo::Baz);`) I’m getting a stack overflow instead.That should definitively not happen.

Comment: @Ferio I've added a potential solution. Your stack overflow happens because `_` will be a `Foo:Bar`, which will then be immediately dropped. But to drop that, you have to call the `drop` method, which will call `mem::replace`, and so on.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Thanks for the solution but I’m still wondering whether there is a real problem or just a lack of documentation. What I was trying to do, is very similar to `Option` + `take` so it must be possible somehow.

Comment: @Ferio there certainly could be a bug in that `drop` pre-decides what variant's destructor will be run, regardless of what happens in the method. I'd suggest filing a bug report to see if the core devs agree that it is an issue.