# How to declare an array of structs and initialize it later?

Tags: arrays, struct, rust

I have a struct:

```rust
struct Point {
    x: u32,
    y: u32,
}
```

I want to have two `Point`s in two different variables. I want to **declare them first and initialize later**. It works fine with separate values:

```rust
let p0: Point;
let p1: Point;

p0 = Point { x: 1, y: 2 };
p1 = Point { x: 2, y: 3 };
```

I want to do the same but with an array:

```rust
let p: [Point; 2];

p[0] = Point { x: 1, y: 2 };
p[1] = Point { x: 2, y: 3 };
```

Doesn't work as I get a compilation error:

```
error[E0381]: use of possibly-uninitialized variable: `p`
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     p[0] = Point { x: 1, y: 2 };
  |     ^^^^ use of possibly-uninitialized `p`
```

Why does it behave differently for single variables and arrays? Can I do it without using `Default::default()`?

Comment: even if rust allow this kind of thing for variable, I would advice to never user this feature. Initialize your variable with the correct value in the first place, this make the code way easier to read, and less error prone. You need to have a strong reason to not initialize your variable when you declare them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust requires that every element in an array is initialized. There's literally nowhere for the compiler to track the initialized state of each value.

The by-hand way to do it involves using unsafe Rust code paired with [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html) and raw pointer manipulation. Then the programmer is responsible for correctly upholding all of the requirements:

```rust
use std::{mem::MaybeUninit, ptr};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: u32,
    y: u32,
}

fn main() {
    // I copied this code from Stack Overflow without reading 
    // the prose that describes why this is or is not safe.
    let p = unsafe {
        // Future: MaybeUninit::uninit_array
        let mut p = MaybeUninit::<[Point; 2]>::uninit();

        // Future: MaybeUninit::first_ptr_mut
        let h = p.as_mut_ptr() as *mut Point;
        ptr::write(h.offset(0), Point { x: 1, y: 2 });
        ptr::write(h.offset(1), Point { x: 2, y: 3 });

        p.assume_init()
    };
}
```

The programmer has to validate that all of the elements have been filled before `assume_init` is called, otherwise the code has undefined behavior.

Instead, it's much easier to use [`ArrayVec`](https://crates.io/crates/arrayvec), which handles all the unsafe logic for you:

```rust
use arrayvec::ArrayVec; // 0.5.1

struct Point {
    x: u32,
    y: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let p = {
        let mut p = ArrayVec::<[Point; 2]>::new();

        p.insert(0, Point { x: 1, y: 2 });
        p.insert(1, Point { x: 2, y: 3 });

        p.into_inner()
    };
}
```

See also:

- [Is there a way to not have to initialize arrays twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26185618/155423)
- [How do I collect into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26757355/155423)
- [How can I update a value in a mutable HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30414424/155423)
- [What is the proper way to initialize a fixed length array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31360993/155423)
- [How can I create a stack-allocated vector-like container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29239586/155423)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are fixed size in Rust and Rust requires that every element in an array is initialized - e.g. no undefined values.

In your case, I would do:

```
let p: [Point; 2] = [Point { x: 1, y: 2 }, Point { x: 2, y: 3 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Rust requires that every element in an array is initialized. Because Rust does not know if the elements in `p` were initialized, the compiler statically prevents you from using them.

Rust does not let you use `null` (in safe code). It does this to prevent *undefined behavior*. If Rust let you use the possibly uninitialized array `p`, this could *potentially* cause a whole lot of runtime errors.

In your case, elements in the `p` may either be initialized, or uninitialized. This looks like a perfect case for `Option`. An `Option<T>` can either be `Some(T)`, or `None`:

```rust
let mut p: [Option<Point>; 2] = [None, None];

p[0] = Some(Point { x: 1, y: 2 });
p[1] = Some(Point { x: 2, y: 3 });
```