# How can I assign to an uninitialised vector without dropping the previous value?

Tags: vector, rust, buffer, unsafe, raw

I have a situation where I know how to initialise a vector, but I don't know the exact order of those elements.

```rust
let mut vector = todo!();
for (index, element) in &hash_map {
    vector[index] = element;
}
```

Now the problem is how to initialise the vector. The elements that it holds are not very lightweight, so I would prefer to cheat a little by creating an uninitialised vector:

```rust
let mut vector = Vec::with_capacity(size);
unsafe { vector.set_len(size) };
```

The problem is that when I later assign the value, I drop the previous element (which is uninitialised garbage) and panic:

```rust
vector[index] = element;
```

How can I assign an element to vector without triggering the default dropping behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pointer::write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.write) or [`ptr::write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.write.html):

```rust
let mut vector: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(2);
unsafe {
    let base = vector.as_mut_ptr();
    base.offset(0).write(42);
    vector.set_len(1);
};
println!("{:?}", vector);
```

But it may be better to use [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html) which is intended for this purpose.

See also:

- [How to declare an array of structs and initialize it later?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64885448/155423)
- [How do I convert a Vec<T> to a Vec<U> without copying the vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48308759/155423)

Comment: Isn't it UB to use `set_len` before `write`?

Comment: @Cerberus ah, good call (["The elements at `old_len`..`new_len` must be initialized"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.52.1/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#safety-2)). I'm a bit surprised Miri didn't yell at me for that.