# How do you efficiently generate a sequence of random bytes on the heap in Rust

Tags: rust, optimization, random, slice

I would like to have a large sequence of random bytes stored on the heap. I only need a reference to the byte sequence itself; I don't need ownership. One of the more prevalent ways of accomplishing this that I've seen is this:

```rust
use rand::RngCore;


let mut v = vec![0; 50_000_000]; // Use a Vec to allocate the memory on the heap
let mut rng = rand::thread_rng(); // A RNG for generating the random bytes

// use rand::RngCore::fill_bytes to fill the allocation with random bytes
rng.fill_bytes(&mut v);
```

This solution seems like it has poor performance because, from what I understand, after the 50 MB of memory is allocated, each byte is initialized to `0` only to be immediately changed to its final random value. This feels very wasteful and expensive. Is there a more efficient way to generate a large sequence of random bytes? Perhaps a solution that allocates, but does not initialize the memory before filling it with random bytes?

Comment: Related: [How can I assign to an uninitialised vector without dropping the previous value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67625026/364696)

Answer (score 1):

For an allocation that large, it almost certainly doesn't matter. "Large enough" allocations (typically in the few hundred KB range IIRC, but it's implementation-dependent) are satisfied directly from the OS allocation routines, which always provide pre-zeroed memory, or memory mapped copy-on-write to the zero page, without actually writing any zeroes after the allocation. The allocator knows this, and doesn't redundantly zero the data. That pre-zeroing by the OS is unavoidable for security reasons, and your program rarely pays anything for it, so it's not something you can optimize further.

For smaller allocations, [using `MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html) can be helpful in specific cases, or [`Vec`'s unsafe `set_len` can be used for similar purposes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.set_len) (allocating with the safe `Vec::with_capacity`, then filling it and setting the length in an `unsafe` block) but it's always going to involve `unsafe` code, and there's really no benefit to it here.

Comment: wow. So you're saying that for large enough `N`, `vec![0; N]` doesn't actually initialize the allocated memory and simply trusts the operating system to provide a pre-zeroed allocation? How can it do this?

Comment: @RBF06: *Every* non-embedded OS *guarantees* that any memory provided by the OS (via `VirtualAlloc` on Windows, `mmap` or `sbrk` on UNIX-likes) is functionally zero-ed, because if it wasn't, a non-kernel level program could acquire information about other programs, programs it may not have permission to interact with, by asking for memory from the OS and checking it for whatever was left behind when the other program returned it to the OS. Windows maintains a pool of background pre-zeroed pages, Linux copy-on-write maps the zero page, etc.

Comment: For small allocations, a heap maintained per-process in user mode satisfies the allocations, and old data from prior allocations and frees could be there (so zeroing costs something, because it isn't necessarily zero to start with), but it's only for smallish allocations; for larger allocations, it doesn't waste the heap, it just asks the OS for the memory directly. You often see similar benefits from using `calloc` in C for large allocations, rather than `malloc`+`memset`: if the allocation is large enough to be zero-ed "for free" by the OS, `calloc` doesn't need to zero it at all.